# How to prepopulate React state array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, state

I am trying to build a grid with React. Each cell in the grid is an object. And to represent the 2D grid I am using an array within an array like following:

```
grid = [
  [{key: value}, {key: value}],
  [{key: value}, {key: value}],
]
```

I have used a helper function to generate the state like the following:

```
export const initialGrid = () => {
  let output = [];

  for (let row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
    output.push([]); // insert a new row
    for (let col = 0; col < 50; col++) {
      output[row].push({});
      output[row][col]['obstacle'] = false;
      output[row][col]['id'] = `${row},${col}`;
    }
  }

  return output;
}
```

Upon importing this function in my React component I am trying to assign the generated state when the component mounts like the following:

```
export const Grid = () => {
  const [grid, setGrid] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function initiateGrid() {
      let temp = await initialGrid();
      setGrid(temp);
    }

    initiateGrid();
  }, [])

  // more code here
}
```

But when I console log my `grid` state variable, I see that the value of the prepopulated state is not being assigned. I am guessing the value is being assigned before the state value is being generated. I also tried `async/await` like assigning the return value of an API but to no avail.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In the initialGrid function, you should be returning a promise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: `initialGrid` is not asynchronous, so no need to `await` that call in `useEffect`. Have you tried doing `useState(initialGrid())`? Because the parameter to `useState` is the "initial state".

Comment: @MattU I did, but the result is the same. I console logged the output in the initialGrid function and it shows the state. So I know that it's getting generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use callback inside setGrid
Inside initialGrid you are not doing any async operations you can directly call that no need for async/await.

```
useEffect(() => {
    function initiateGrid() {
        let temp = initialGrid();
        setGrid(previousState => temp);
    }
    initiateGrid();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution

```
initialGrid = () => {
  let output = [];

  for (let row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
    output.push([]); // insert a new row
    for (let col = 0; col < 50; col++) {
      output[row].push({});
      output[row][col]['obstacle'] = false;
      output[row][col]['id'] = `${row},${col}`;
    }
  }

  return output;
}

const App = () => {
  const [grid, setGrid] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
       setGrid( initialGrid());
  }, [])
  console.log(grid)
  // more code here
  return (<>
  <h1>Working</h1>
      {JSON.stringify(grid)}
      </>)
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />,
document.getElementById("root"))
```